# How does Uniswap forntend caculate the path(route) for a specific pair?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

Say I wanna swap CVC for KEEP, Uniswap forntend will shows a path(route):cvc>eth>usdt>keep，
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTI7W.png)

How does it get this path? Where can I get this part of code?

Comment: The image in the question is not broken.